# Ionic2 identify back view

Tags: ionic2

How could I identify in ionic2 the back/caller view?

in ioni1 I was using

```
var backView:ionic.View = this.$ionicHistory.backView();
backView.stateName === 'app.view_I_want_to_test';
```

I was thinking about getting the view controller, but don't know how to test if that view controller is the view I'm interested in.

```
let lastView:ViewController = this.navController.getPrevious(this.navController.getActive());
then???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which I don't like because I've to do a dirty "any" cast to access a private value for the comparison but following code do the job:

```
onPageDidEnter() {
    // this.navController.last() strangely equals the view which entered
    let previousView:ViewController = this.navController.getPrevious(this.navController.last());

    if (previousView != null && (<any> previousView).instance instanceof MyPage) {
        doSomeStuffs();
   } else {
        doSomeOtherStuffs();
   }
}
```